# Clear Google Maps API markers through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am playing around with the Google Maps API v3 for a project I am building. I have managed to place markers on the map at the location the user clicks at however I want to have a clear all button to remove all the markers. I have looked at various answers on here and tried different methods. I have also consulted the Google Maps API documentation however all the methods I have tried do not work. It should be noted the map can have multiple markers.

The code I have is below:

```
///The function addLatLng is called when the user clicks on the Map
   function addLatLng(event) {

  // This code adds the marker to the map
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    title: '#' + path.getLength(),

map: map

  });



}

   ///The clearall function is called when a button is clicked
function clearall() {
    poly.setMap(null);//This clears the polyline that is drawn and works correctly

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Google Maps API doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#remove) calling setMap only remove the marker from the map but not delete it. If you want to delete multiple markers, you could do as in [Google Maps API example given](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove) :

1/ When adding a marker, pushing it in an array

2/ To remove all markers : create a function that takes this array as an argument, and apply setMap() on each of the array's element through a for loop.

3/ To delete all markers (i.e from memory) after remove : create a function to call setMap(null) on each marker in your array (which according to Google delete the marker) and delete all the markers from your array (e.g. markersArray = [])

You can find corresponding google example code in my second reference.

Comment: I have tried something like that however the way you have explained it has cleared it up. Ill have a play around doing that and see where I get thanks.

Comment: Glad to help.If this solution ends up to be the right one, please mark it as an answer ;)